# Comparison of two lists containing 'ValueTupel'

Tags: .net

I have two lists containing ValueTuples of the same kind. Now I try to use the IEnumerable.Except function but I get a runtime error, telling me, that the values were not compatible.
And no, this isn't the case !!

Is Except usable with ValueTuple or is this generally a problem?

Ok, here a sample code snippet:

```
Dim l1 As New List(Of ValueTuple(Of String, String))
Dim l2 As New List(Of ValueTuple(Of String, String))

Dim vt = (Code:="Code1", Text:="aaa")
l1.Add(vt)
l2.Add(vt)
vt = (Code:="Code2", Text:="bbb")
l1.Add(vt)

Dim diff As List(Of ValueTuple(Of String, String))
diff = l1.Except(l2)
' diff should contain the element (Code:="Code2", Text:="bbb"), cause it is only a member of l1
' but this call fails

l1.Sort()
' this call works, but how can .Sort() work, if there is a problem with the comparison of elements?
```

Thanks for helping

Gerhard

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: Indeed - please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.